# Google Web Toolkit and RPC

Tags: rest, gwt, client

I am new to web development. in GWT it uses its own set of RPC to call server side methods from the client. Now my question is that when we are doing development using plain html/css we can call a php script to b executed. So when we are designing using GWT can it call a Java program sitting on the server and if yes how does it call it? ALso apart from RestyGWT how can we use RESTful WS via GWT on the client side to call the java programs sitting on the server. Thanking you in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

Expose a URL to call your Java app functionality and use GWT's RequestBuilder.

```
private static String GET_SERVER_URL(String parameters) {
    // make up your Java url here along with any parameters
    ...
    return url;
}

RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET,
            GET_SERVER_URL(parameters));
try {
    builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
        public void onError(Request request, Throwable caught) {}
        public void onReponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {}
    } catch (RequestException e) {}
}
```